# snapshot option of find method not working

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

My code

Method 1:

```
...
var cursor = collection.find({}, {snapshot: true});
//i made sure to insert a new document to the collection before the below timer fires
setTimeout(function(){
    cursor.each(function(err, docu){
        console.log("cursor items", docu);
    })
}, 15000);
```

Method 2:

```
var cursor = collection.find({}, {snapshot: true});
cur.nextObject(function(err, item) {
    console.log("Read the first doc alone", item)
})
//i made sure to insert a new document to the collection before the below timer fires
setTimeout(function(){
    cursor.each(function(err, docu){
        console.log("cursor items", docu);
    })
}, 15000);
```

For both the methods, i started the application, within the next 15 secs i inserted a row to the same db manually.

Method 1 outputs the rows that already exists and the row that i inserted in that 15 secs.

Method 2 outputs the first row immediately and this method is not printing the row that i inserted in that 15 secs, irrespective of {snapshot: true} or {snapshot: false}

**Questions**

1. Why '`snapshot`' option of `find` method is not working in method 1
2. Giving `{snapshot: true}` or `{snapshot: false}` in method 2 does not prints the
   document that i inserted manually.
3. Please let me know any site, that explains the behavior of cursors.

Tried as per @Scott Hernandez like below, but the newly inserted documents are coming in the snapshot cursor.

```
var SimpleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name:{type:String}
}, {collection:'simple'});
var SimpleModel = mongoose.model('SimpleModel', SimpleSchema);

//var snapshotQuery = SimpleModel.find({}).setOptions({snapshot:true}); //try method 1
var snapshotQuery = SimpleModel.find({}).snapshot(true);                //try method 2

setTimeout(function(){
    snapshotQuery.exec(function(err, docs){
        if(err){
            console.log("ERROR", err);
        }else{
            console.log("setTimeout", docs);
        }
    })
},10000)
```

Comment: db.collection.find().snapshot() is not working in mongo latest version,Use mongo 3.2 for using snapshot

Answer (score 0):

The format is incorrect. You must use the [snapshot method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/query.html) as described in the docs.

Comment: I have updated the question giving how i tried as per your comments. But still the new manually inserted rows are coming the snapshot cursor.